# Java Swing: how to create assist functionality to teach user how to use the software?

Tags: java, swing, content-assist

Is there a library out there that can facilitate in creating assist or automated guide that tells users what action to take?

Like it should notice the user is running the software for the first time so it will say click this button, and when the user does, it will explain other features.

sort of like what Youtube's video editor does but I wonder if this is achievable in swing.

I don't know what you call this...but below is a good example to aim for but something that works for Java Swing.

http://jeffpickhardt.com/guiders/

Comment: something very new, I have never tried in my apps.

Comment: I vote for this/ese library(ies) too +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using JPanel or image and mouse events by setting their visbility properties. I haven't tried it but, I think I can...

I used  these libraries which are for rich applications

```
http://java.net/projects/animatedtransitions/
http://java.net/projects/timingframework/
```

let me know if you found anything new.

thanks

from
vinay

Comment: what about doing overlays on lightweight and heavyweight components? I think that is the missing equation. nice suggestions +1